# How to output a word file with Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, cpu-word

Some months ago, I learned Flask and use it for personal purposes.
I made some basic websites to make my data science projects more "user-friendly".

Like this one :

https://intense-dawn-67915.herokuapp.com/

(it could take a while to open)

Here I told Flask take my input (some movie name we need to write) and output some movies recommandations based on an recommendation algorithm with cosine similarity. Now I would like to know if it's possible to tell Flask this :

- Take this sentence as input (instead of a movie name)
- Output a word file in a folder with this sentences

I guess it's less complicated but I'm not familiar with Flask so I need some tips to begin with.

Comment: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or slightly easier using templates https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks ! I will check it asap ! I'll keep you in touch :)

Comment: I didn't see it was python docx. I know this package but I would like to know how to incorporate it  Flask

Comment: You can create the file in memory and send the file in the response.